# Is there a way to remove magic numbers from a XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl, code-reuse, magic-numbers

I have a WSDL with some types defined. Some elements accept lists of elements and on the service return I also have elements with list of values (or other elements).

As a result I have some magic numbers in the XSD (e.g. minOccurs="10", maxOccurs="250" etc). These values 10, 250 etc are repeated throughout the XSD types.

Is there a way to declare them as some sort of constants? and then reuse them by name for the minOccurs and maxOccurs attributes?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. The only thing you could do is to pre-process the schema using some sort of template processor before loading.

Answer (score 0):

XSD is XML so you could use entities defined in a DTD:

```
minOccurs="&minOccurs;"
```